# Circular Tally Counter Not Rolling Over

Tags: java, circular-list

I was practicing my java and was trying to make a simple counter with rollover at max, but for some reason it isn't rolling over. Any advice?

```
if(count++ < max){
    click();
 }
```

Comment: How are you using your tally class? A way to reproduce your issue would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with `count++`. It evaluates to the current value of the `count`, then increments afterward. So if `count` is 3, and `max` is 3, `count++ > max` will return false, and then increment `count`. It looks like you want `++count`, which increments, and then evaluates.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I totally forgot about that! Thanks.